# NSMutableURLRequest, JSON convert to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am in the process of retrieving data via "JSON" from a `NSMutableURLRequest`.  The data comes back and I convert to a dictionary via:

```
 NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:companyData //1
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&e];
```

The problem I am having is, of the data coming back, when I take it and:

```
 NSArray* parameterInfo = [json objectForKey:@"parameters"];
```

The returned data is in the form of the below, which is showing as a `NSDictionary` but I can't for the life of me, figure out how to convert that to a data I can read.  Meaning, the  "parameterInfo array" item, how do I read it as an `NSDictionary` and then able to programmatically use the data.

As you can see from the below, the "KEY" is a dictionary.

I hope this makes sense.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Geo:

```
 2014-05-14 15:20:26.343 testdata[12052:60b] parameterInfo:  {
key =     {
    "@name" = "Product_Search";
    value =         (
                    {
            "@name" = Heated;
            "@totalCount" = 2;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = Drill;
            "@totalCount" = 2;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = Heat;
            "@totalCount" = 1;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = Sprayer;
            "@totalCount" = 1;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = Paint;
            "@totalCount" = 1;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = 2653;
            "@totalCount" = 2;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = "0884-20";
            "@totalCount" = 1;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = Hand;
            "@totalCount" = 1;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = Vacu;
            "@totalCount" = 1;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = "Drill Driver";
            "@totalCount" = 1;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = Blower;
            "@totalCount" = 3;
        },
                    {
            "@name" = Blow;
            "@totalCount" = 5;
        }
    );
```

Comment: can you post the url link for json here. for try:-  change [json objectForKey:@"parameters"]; to [json objectForKey:@"key"];, it will return a dictionary. change parameterInfo from array to dictionary.

Comment: [json objectForKey:@"key"] returns nothing.

NSArray to NSDictionary does exact same thing.  Shows one entry {0] with a key of "key" and the value as and __NSCFDictionary. Thoughts?

Comment: if you can post the json log here , then i can tell you the exact code, without that i can only guess.

Comment: Hotdog that did it!  You are awesome.  Sure wish I could have figured this out myself.  Thanks again so much!

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes and then you won't have to come here begging each time the JSON is different from the example you're copying.

Comment: The key to JSON in Obj-C is realizing that arrays can nest inside dictionaries and vice versa.

Comment: @OwenHartnett - That's one of the keys to JSON in any language -- it's a very general notation, but maps very well to common data structures in several languages.  It only gets complicated when folks try to make it complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
 NSDictionary* parameterInfo = [json objectForKey:@"parameters"];
 NSArray * myParameters = [[parameterInfo objectForKey:@"key"] objectForKey:@"value"];
```

json is a dictionary, and so is the value returned by @"key", inside that is the Array you seek.

Answer (score 3):

Forget the whole `objectForKey` thing, it's just

```
NSArray *values = json[@"parameters"][@"key"][@"value];
```